# Is there a way for a web page to programmatically load Devtools and set it to a responsive mobile view?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, redux-devtools

I would like to be able to program a webpage or script to instantiate devtools and load the page into the mobile responsive view. This way when I do a remote demo of a webapp to a client they can just open it in mobile view or I can make a page always load in a mobile view no matter whos browser it is in?